# Box2D object gets stuck when should destroy the objects it's stuck between

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I'm using Cocos2D and Box2D for a game with some physics. There's an occasional problem where my "ball/bullet/destroyer" object gets stuck between two "target" objects and takes forever to work its way out.

This is silly because a collision between the bullet and the target object should destroy the target. (Normally, of course, this works fine.)

It hasn't gone to sleep as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9451746/box2d-circular-body-stuck-in-corners), because it's vibrating around like crazy in the tiny little space between the two objects.

I have the bullet as a "bullet" object in Box2D.

Is there some minimum distance that the objects have to be in a previous frame in order to count as a collision?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick was that for a given "cluster" of contacts, the Box2D contact listener calls (in this order):

```
BeginContact()
PreSolve() // As many times as necessary
PostSolve() // As many times as necessary
EndContact()
```

I was, by default, only getting contacts from `EndContact()` which meant that a series of fast collisions would all happen before their effects were evaluated. I moved my `destroy`-type code into `PostSolve()` and all was well.